# beautifulSoup soup.select() returning empty for css selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I am trying to parse some links from this site
https://news.ycombinator.com/

I want to select a specific table

```
document.querySelector("#hnmain > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table")
```

I know there css selector limitations for bs4. But the problem is I can't even select  as simple as `#hnmain > tbody` with `soup.select('#hnmain > tbody')` as it is returning **empty**

with below code, I'm unable to parse tbody whereas the with js I did (screenshot)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
print("-"*100)
print("Hackernews parser")
print("-"*100)
url="https://news.ycombinator.com/"
res=requests.get(url)
html=res.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
table=soup.select('#hnmain > tbody')
print(table)
```

OUT:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
[]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting the html tag **tbody** from beautifulsoup or the curl script.
It means

```
soup.select('tbody')
```

returns empty list. This is the **same reason** for you to get an empty list.

To just extract the links you are looking for just do

```
soup.select("a.storylink")
```

It will get the links that you want from the site.

Comment: thank you!! your approach is good for getting the main story links, but i need to fetch more attribute from each post, like upvote_count, comment_count, url_to_right_of_main_url, posted_ago where these items are span/a without having a specific classes. please help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going to through the body and table why not go directly to the links? I tested this and it worked well:

```
links=soup.select('a',{'class':'storylink'})
```

If you want the table, since there is only one per page you don't need to go through the other elements either - you can go straight to it.

```
table = soup.select('table')
```

Comment: theres total of 3 tables in that page

Comment: oh yeah my bad. Well then you can parse based off of class ID or something else but I wouldn't go go through the attribute hierarchy if I were you.

Comment: your's approach is good for getting the main story links, but i need to fetch more attribute from each post, like upvote_count, comment_count, site_url where these items are span/a without having a specific classes. please help

Comment: There are <td> attributes with class ID of 'subtext' which has a lot of the post info. The span attributes also have ID's depending on the information stored - look through the HTML carefully and find patterns for the information you want to grab.

Answer (score 1):

Data is arranged in groups of 3 rows where the third row is an empty row used for spacing. Loop the top rows and use next_sibling to grab the associated second row at each point. bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
top_rows = soup.select('.athing')

for row in top_rows:
    title = row.select_one('.storylink')
    print(title.text)
    print(title['href'])
    print('https://news.ycombinator.com/' + row.select_one('.sitebit a')['href'])
    next_row = row.next_sibling
    print(next_row.select_one('.score').text)
    print(next_row.select_one('.hnuser').text)
    print(next_row.select_one('.age a').text)
    print(next_row.select_one('a:nth-child(6)').text)
    print(100*'-')
```